# How to change shadow color of AppBar?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to change shadow elevation color of the `AppBar` but can't find any property for that.
I went to the original implementation as well but cant find any property to change shadow color.

```
AppBar(
        title: Image.asset(
          "images/toolbar_logo.webp",
          width: 80,
          height: 50,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: white,
      ),
```

I cant wrap the `AppBar` inside a `Material Widget`.
I know i can avoid the app bar property and create a custom class and add it to my body of `Scaffold`,
but is it possible to change using shadow color of `AppBar`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a way to change the colour of the default shadow but you can get around it by wrapping your `AppBar` in a `Container` which is inside a `PreferredSize` widget:

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.red,
                offset: Offset(0, 2.0),
                blurRadius: 4.0,
              )
            ]),
            child: AppBar(
              elevation: 0.0,
              title: Text("Test"),
            ),
          ),
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        ),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this depending on theme??

Comment: output is highly weird and horrable.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is a bit expired. You can do this in two ways:

Changing directly through the `AppBar` property:

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(shadowColor: Colors.green),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or by using the `Theme`:

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          shadowColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shadowColor property of Appbar to color to paint the shadow below the app bar.